# Nine isosceles triangles whose angles give a fixed integer both with sine and cosine.

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, triangles, pi, polygons

$a+b>c,a+c>b,b+c>a$

I have a maximum of nine triangles whose perimeters equal $11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $1$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $2$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $3$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $4$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $5$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $6$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $7$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $8$

side of triangle are $5$ and $5$ and base $9$

> $ \cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C+\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C=3$

For:the side of 5,5 and 1
the angles are

> $0.1^2+0.1^2+0.98^2+\sqrt0.99^2+\sqrt0.99^2+\sqrt(1-0.98^2)^2=3$

and sides of 5,5 and 4

> $0.4^2+0.4^2+0.68^2+\sqrt0.84^2+\sqrt0.84^2+\sqrt(1-0.68^2)^2=3$

Question : Does finding the sine of all three angles, which are fixed integers would  be easier to construct $pi$ using Taylor's series for $\arcsin$? The sum of  3 $\arcsin\theta$ are $pi$

Comment: I do not get the exact question. Are you looking for triples $(a,b,c)$ , such that a triangle with these sides has angles such that the expression given in the yellow box is an integer ?

Comment: $\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C \color{red}{+}\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C=3$ will work for any triangle ... use $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x =1$ three times.

Comment: @Peter you are correct,when I said whole numbers I mean fixed integer and by trying to resolve the angles both in Sine and Cosine ,these nine triangles are the only ones that gives you whole number with the help of square root.